# Transfer app from one account to another with same SKU number

Tags: iphone, app-store, transfer

I want to transfer a application from one account to another and i get this error:
    You cannot transfer apps with a App product ID that is the same as a product ID used by the recipient's app.

The Apple ID for both applications is different.
The only thing in common is the SKU number which i have to admit, is poorly chosen for both apps - 01.
I don't want to re-submit my apps so i can choose a new SKU number for any one of them.
Is there any way i can transfer them ?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't mix questions and answers. It is hard to fugure out your initial question after reading the complete post.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot transfer an app from one account to another if in the destination account you have another app with the same SKU number as the one you're transfering.

Today i received an answer from Apple regarding this question:

"It is not possible to transfer an app that has an identical SKU/product ID to another app on the recipient's account. If you would like the app to be distributed on the App Store through this specific account, you will need to remove it from sale, delete it from the current account, and then upload it as a new app in the new account. Deleting the app will enable you to use the app name in the new account.

When you move the app to the new account, you will disable current customers from receiving automatic and free updates of your app. Also, all customer reviews, rating, and ranking information will be reset.

Deleting an app permanently removes the app and any associated In-App Purchases from iTunes Connect. After the app has been deleted, you won’t be able to reuse your app name and SKU. Also, if you have uploaded a binary or enabled the app for the iAd Network, you won’t be able to reuse your Bundle ID."